# Using Render Props in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am developing a React-Native component that is supposed to be used as a 'Select' picker, that displays a `FlatList`. I would like the renderItem function of the `FlatList` to be customizable, in essence I would like to pass a custom render function to the `SelectPicker` component which will be responsible for rendering the List items.

In the `StandardPicker` component I have a render function which looks like the following:

```
render() {
  const { range } = this.props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.modal}>
      <FlatList
        data={range}
        renderItem={this.renderListItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and the `renderListItem` function looks like this

```
renderListItem({ item, index }) {
  const { onSelectItem, renderItem } = this.props;

  const renderedItem = renderItem ? (
    renderItem()
  ) : null

  return (
    <TouchableNative
      key={index}
      onPress={() => {
        onSelectItem(index);
      }}
    >
      {renderedItem}
    </TouchableNative>
  );
}
```

Now in a different component I am rendering the `StandardPicker` and passing a render function like so

```
renderCustomItem() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Testing</Text>
      <Text>Test 2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

<StandardPicker
  range={this.listItems}
  onSelectItem={item=>
    this.setState({ selectedItem: item})
  }
  renderItem={this.renderCustomItem}
/>
```

However I end up getting an error `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Is there something I am missing or can this not be done in React-Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels you're complicating this more than you need to, you can absolutely pass a render function to a Component but it's much easier to just pass the body, now the error you're getting seems to be some kind of import/spelling error as one of the objects you're using is in-fact as the code says, `undefined` now I would need a better look at your code to find out exactly where it's happening but either way you can feel free to shorten your function like this:

```
renderListItem({ item, index }) {
  const { onSelectItem, renderItem } = this.props;

  return (
    <TouchableNative
      key={index}
      onPress={() => {
        onSelectItem(index);
      }}
    >
      {renderItem}
    </TouchableNative>
  );
}
```

As if it's undefined the JSX won't render anything there either way.

Comment: Yep you were right! In the component where the `renderCustomItem` function is, `Text` was being imported from `react-redux` instead of `react-native`, hence the undefined error. Thank you for your help!